# Why does "+" operator work even without space between the operands in Scala

Tags: scala, operator-overloading, infix-notation

I am learning Scala and came to know that the below code works because "+" is a method in `Int` class (which takes one argument and returns another Int instance).

For example: `1 + 2` is equivalent to `1.+(2)`

My question is then how is this expression working?
`1+2` // (no space before and after +)

Comment: The same way, white spaces are meaningless for most languages so the parser just ignores them. You can also write `1           +             2`.

Comment: Multiple statements have to be separated by a new line or a semicolon `;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Language lexer](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/01-lexical-syntax.html) is able to split identifiers and literals here:

- `1` - int literal
- `+` - identifier
- `2` - int literal

As long as lexer is able to split things correctly (here it always can) parser can unambiguously parse the result.

As long as you aren't e.g. merging keywords with identifiers because there is no space between them, white characters don't matter.